# Should Entity objects execute code?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Should entity objects for databases execute code inside them? Because I'm hearing mixed answers from the people around me. Some people tell me if should only contain fields you set and others said you can do whatever you want inside them.

I wrote an example below so you know what I mean (Pretend that I have all of the appropriate try catches and throws:

```
@Entity
public class Man {

    private Long id;
    private final String name;
    private final double height;
    private final double weight;
    private final double bmi;

    public Man(String name) {

        ManData data = new ManData(name);

        this.name = name;
        this.height = data.getHeight;
        this.weight = data.getWeight;
        this.bmi = BMI.calculate(height, weight);

    }

}
```

1) Pretend that the `ManData` object gets its information from the internet.
2) The `bmi` is also calculated from received data, not passed through.

Is do this kind of thing inside Entities okay?

Comment: I think it is.  If BMI is part of the state of this object, then it's perfectly acceptable to perform the calculation.  "Okay"?  There are no object-oriented police who will knock on your door Minority Report style.  It's your code.  Do what you think is right, according to your best understanding of good practice, and change it if you learn that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Long Answer:**

Martin Fowler has a great blog post on Anemic Domains here:http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

He defines them as:

> The basic symptom of an Anemic Domain Model is that at first blush it looks like the real thing. There are objects, many named after the nouns in the domain space, and these objects are connected with the rich relationships and structure that true domain models have. The catch comes when you look at the behavior, and you realize that there is hardly any behavior on these objects, making them little more than bags of getters and setters. Indeed often these models come with design rules that say that you are not to put any domain logic in the the domain objects. Instead there are a set of service objects which capture all the domain logic. These services live on top of the domain model and use the domain model for data.

**tl;dr**

Yes adding more code than getters and setters is fine in your domain objects.

edited to fix spelling

Comment: worth noting, your ORM entities should probably NOT be your actual domain objects though, since it's easy to become constrained by the ORM and paint yourself into a corner. the database should be "hidden" behind an abstraction to keep the domain model clean imo.